# Pandas to_sql and JSON data

Tags: sqlite, python

I'm in the process of creating a Python application which takes in a JSON encoded file and stores the information in an SQLite database in memory.

The JSON file in itself is essentially a Database for another application so I have created tables for each of the record paths in the file with the needed foreign keys.
The issue I'm having is inserting the data into the tables using the pandas `.to_sql()` method.

I get the following error currently:
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 12: type 'list' is not supported`

My assumption is that some of the records contained within a particular record path are infact themselves another record path.

An example of this is:

```
      "OID":"{1C2CBE9F-60F7-4932-ACBE-01EB2637F24A}",
      "SID":"{7E277613-F650-4F60-8FFB-5DB630FF0544}",
      "Constraints":      
      [
        {
          "Sub":2,
          "Min":2,
          "Max":2        
        },
        {
          "Sub":1,
          "Min":0,
          "Max":0        
        }      
      ]    
    },
```

I am content with storing the Constraints record path as a text/string column type as I'm not querying anything in it directly from the database but need it there to reference later on in other processing, but I can't seem to get it into the database at all. Pandas identify it as an object.

Some more relevant code:

```
options_df = pd.json_normalize(json_file, record_path=['Options'])
options_df.to_sql('options_SS', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Using Python 3.11

What am I missing? Or any pointers would be greatly appreciated!